# Can i automatically kill any application that uses more than a certain percentage of the CPU and/or RAM?

Tags: cpu, ram, kill

What i need from my computer, now that it's summer at least, should never use a lot of resources - when applications do so it's because of some kind of bug or memory leak.

Is there any way to automatically kill any application that uses, for example, more than 15% of the CPU or more than 450 mbs of RAM?

I would like to use this trick, if it's possible, at either 11.04 or 11.10.

Comment: Honestly, this just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Why? It is dangerous, most probably, but not a bad idea if one uses it correctly. It's definitely better than having a strange leak on one of chrome's pages cause the fans of the notebook to start attacking my ears without showing mercy :D

Comment: I agree: bad idea. The fans going crazy is far more better option than killing random processes. What if you kill X? Or worse... kill something that is writing to disc? Would fixing the memory leak or the bug not be a lot saner? >:)

Comment: Ok there, any way to do this for certain apps only? chrome/compiz/unity for example?

As for "fixing the bug" , i like testing the latest releases of each application - from the time i report a memory leak to the time it is fixed and my application updated , my head will probably explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were worried about high cpu usage I would do what supercomputer admins do and use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) also stay away from the main offenders, continually updating websites,flash and coverting or watching video and things should stay fairly stable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would prefer it if they were killed (unity and compiz restart when they are killed and chrome processes only take their tab down with them) but it seems (from the comments above) that doing something like that is somehow "not cool".

Anyway, this idea can become an alternative that is probably worth the compromise, thanks.