# Automatically kill a process if it exceeds a given amount of RAM

Tags: monitor, process, memory

I work on large-scale datasets. When testing new software, a script will sometimes sneak up on me, quickly grab all available RAM, and render my desktop unusable.  I'd like a way to set a RAM limit for a process so that if it exceeds that amount, it will be killed automatically. A language-specific solution probably won't work, as I use all sorts of different tools (R, Perl, Python, Bash, etc).

So is there some sort of process-monitor that will let me set a threshold amount of RAM and automatically kill a process if it uses more?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54202/can-i-automatically-kill-any-application-that-uses-more-than-a-certain-percentage

Comment: @ Uri : At that thread i only got a partial (only for the cpu part of my question) - and not optimal - answer. 
He asks about RAM usage.

Comment: Uri, there's a complete lack of useful ideas in that thread. Posting a link to it isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Hrmm - this superuser thread seems to have a reasonable suggestion using ulimit: http://superuser.com/questions/66383/restrict-ram-for-user-or-process

Answer (score 15):

**I would strongly advise not to do it**. As suggested by @chrisamiller , setting ulimit will limit the RAM available with process.

But still if you are insisting then follow this procedure.

1. Save the following script as `killif.sh`:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   if [ $# -ne 2 ];
   then
       echo "Invalid number of arguments"
       exit 0
   fi

   while true;
   do
       SIZE=$(pmap $1|grep total|grep -o "[0-9]*")
       SIZE=${SIZE%%K*}
       SIZEMB=$((SIZE/1024))
       echo "Process id =$1 Size = $SIZEMB MB"
       if [ $SIZEMB -gt $2 ]; then
           printf "SIZE has exceeded.\nKilling the process......"
           kill -9 "$1"
           echo "Killed the process"
           exit 0
       else
           echo "SIZE has not yet exceeding"
       fi

       sleep 10
   done
   ```
2. Now make it executable.

   ```
   chmod +x killif.sh
   ```
3. Now run this script on terminal. Replace `PROCID` with actual process id and `SIZE` with size in MB.

   ```
   ./killif.sh PROCID SIZE
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   ./killif.sh 132451 100
   ```

   If `SIZE` is 100 then process will be killed if its RAM usage goes up beyond 100 MB.

**Caution:** You know what are you trying to do. Killing process is not a good idea. If that process has any shutdown or stop command then edit the script and replace `kill -9` command with that `shutdown` command.

Comment: i would consider putting little sleep there, for example sleep 0.5...

Comment: @George Edison How did you do that. When I tried to paste, it was giving me weirdly formatted text.
Denwerko: Where would you like to put the sleep. I have already put a sleep of 10 seconds in the while loop

Comment: Thanks for the solution, as noted below, I may check it out. Why all the dire warnings about killing processes, though? Cluster management software (LSF, PBS, et al) does this all the time when a process exceeds the amount of resources that it requested, with no dire consequences. I agree that this is not a good solution for new users who are likely to misapply it, but in the right circumstances, this can be quite useful.

Comment: @chrisamiller I have put up a warning for future readers. In your case, you know the implications but future reader of this post might not be aware of such implications.

Comment: @Amey: All you need to do is insert 4 spaces in front of each line. Since you were using bullets, you would need to insert 8 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why not to do it?

Answer (score 11):

I hate to be the guy who answers his own question, but this morning I found an alternative method, wrapped into a nice little utility. It'll limit CPU time or memory consumption:

https://github.com/pshved/timeout

I'm giving this one a shot first but upvotes to Amey Jah for the nice answer. I'll check it out if this one fails me.

Comment: +1 Answering your own question [is OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `prlimit` tool, from the `util-linux` package. It runs a program with resource limits. It uses the `prlimit` system call to set up the limits, which are then enforced purely by the kernel.

You can configure 16 limits, including:

- maximum amount of CPU time in seconds
- maximum number of user processes
- maximum resident set size ("used memory")
- maximum size a process may lock into memory
- size of virtual memory
- maximum number of open files
- maximum number of file locks
- maximum number of pending signals
- maximum bytes in POSIX message queues

Answer (score 2):

This was too big to fit a comment. I modified Amey's original script to include a `pgrep`, so instead of having to manually enter the process id, you can just exclude by name. For example, `./killIf.sh chrome 4000` kills any chrome process that exceeds 4GB in memory usage.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# $1 is process name
# $2 is memory limit in MB

if [ $# -ne 2 ];
then
    echo "Invalid number of arguments"
    exit 0
fi

while true;
do
    pgrep "$1" | while read -r procId;
    do
        SIZE=$(pmap $procId | grep total | grep -o "[0-9]*")
        SIZE=${SIZE%%K*}
        SIZEMB=$((SIZE/1024))
        echo "Process id = $procId Size = $SIZEMB MB"
        if [ $SIZEMB -gt $2 ]; then
            printf "SIZE has exceeded.\nKilling the process......"
            kill -9 "$procId"
            echo "Killed the process"
            exit 0
        else
            echo "SIZE has not yet exceeding"
        fi
    done

    sleep 1
done
```

Be careful to select a narrow grep string and a big enough memory limit to not unnecessarily kill unintended processes.

Comment: works like a charm. helps to keep the eternally memory leaking telegram desktop app in check.

Comment: I might suggest one improvement - allow to specify multiple processes, create an array and loop over them.